# likelihood ratio test 0 degrees of freedom?

Tags: likelihood-ratio, degrees-of-freedom, mixed-model

Would the results from a likelihood ratio test with 0 degrees of freedom not be interpretable? From what I understand, by definition when the degrees of freedom = 0, chi-squared = 0 thus making the p-value quite low, which makes me hesitant about being able to interpret the results.

I am comparing two linear mixed effects models where one model had a max gradient of 0.006 during fitting triggering warnings of conversion (in case that is related).

Comment: What formula are you using to calculate the degrees of freedom?

Comment: I'd say if anything, then the p-value is 1 when you have 0 df. But I also don't think it's defined.

Comment: I didn't actually calculate the degrees of freedom by hand...I had used the R package lme4's lmer to create my models and lmerTest::anova to compare them